# Postgres Cross tab does not get values in right columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I have a table like below

```
create table example as select * from (values
(1, 'k1', 'v1'),
(2, 'k1', 'v2'),
(3, 'k1', 'v3'),
(4, 'k2', 'v1'),
(5, 'k2', 'v5'),
(123, 'firstName', 'John'),
(123, 'lastName', 'Doe')) as l(id, key, value);

select * from example order by id asc, key asc;
 id  |    key    | value
-----+-----------+-------
   1 | k1        | v1
   2 | k1        | v2
   3 | k1        | v3
   4 | k2        | v1
   5 | k2        | v5
 123 | firstName | John
 123 | lastName  | Doe
(7 rows)
```

My crosstab is showing

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select * from crosstab('select * from example order by id asc, key asc;') as ct(id INT, k1 TEXT, k2 TEXT, k3 TEXT, fn TEXT, ln TEXT);
 id  |  k1  | k2  | k3 | fn | ln
-----+------+-----+----+----+----
   1 | v1   |     |    |    |
   2 | v2   |     |    |    |
   3 | v3   |     |    |    |
   4 | v1   |     |    |    |
   5 | v5   |     |    |    |
 123 | John | Doe |    |    |
(6 rows)
```

I was hoping that the value v1 and v5 would be in column k2

Where did I go wrong?

Tried different modification to the query but could not come up with solution.

Comment: indeed, the query in psql `select * from example order by id asc, key asc \crosstabview` shows the correct result.